# Is there a reference by url widget type for term reference field as we have it for node reference field?

Tags: nodes, entities, users, taxonomy-terms

Is there a module for term reference as we have "Node reference url widget" module for node reference field. So that I can auto-populates a term reference field with a value from the URL.

Comment: what would be the purpose of the same?

Comment: With Drupal 7, in a custom content type I want a field to be automatically populated with related term.

Comment: have you checked http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

Comment: content type A and B has parent & child relationship respectively. Content type A has term reference field called Author. I want that field in Content type B to be autoppopulated.

Comment: There is a module to take care of that http://drupal.org/project/relation

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing is RSpliet's sandbox module:

https://drupal.org/sandbox/RSpliet/1416486